# JSON.SET in redis cli and stackexchange.redis it's showing exception

Tags: docker, .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cli

I'm trying to set and get JSON results in redis with redis-om anyway it uses Stackexchange.Redis even with that the same exception repects.

```cs
    using System;
    using StackExchange.Redis;
    namespace test
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                var muxe = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
                var db = muxe.GetDatabase();
                var JSONResult = db.CreateTransaction();
                db.Execute("JSON.SET", "dog:1", "$", "{\"name\":\"Honey\",\"breed\":\"Greyhound\"}");
                db.Execute("JSON.GET", "dog:1", "$.breed");
                JSONResult.Execute();
                Console.WriteLine("I'm ok");
    
    
            }
        }
    }
Exception: StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: 'ERR unknown command `JSON.SET`,
```

Comment: How did you run the server? it seems like the JSON module is missing.
See redis-stack for more details https://redis.io/docs/stack/

Comment: yes I used Redis alpine image so the module is missed

Comment: Why did you delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74299901/method-that-add-list-of-taskstring ?

Comment: I'll repost the same @Enigmativity

Comment: @JeevananthanS - When will you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed with Redis moudle because alpine image only have core funs some of the modules are not present with the same. please check the redis modules.

```
redis-cli info modules
```